# a set is invariant under translation for a certain measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue null set and $\mu$ is a positive $\sigma$-finite measure living on $A$ (i.e. $\mu(A^c)=0$) such that 
$$
\mu(A+r)=\mu(A),\forall r\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$
does this imply that $\mu=0$?

I think of this when I am learning the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem and the invariant property under translation of Lebesgue measure. I think the answer is yes but still need more justification. 
Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Fubini's theorem, we have
$$
\mu(A)=\int_0^1 \mu(A+r)\,dr =\int_0^1\int 1_{A+r}(y)\,d\mu(y)\,dr=\int \int_0^1 1_{A+r}(y)\,dr\,d\mu(y)\leq \int \lambda(y-A)\,d\mu(y)=0,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Here, I used that $\lambda(y-A)=0$ since $\lambda(A)=0$ (and by elementary properties of the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: beautiful! I was wondering how to use that property and your method seems to fit it perfectly!